# Magento frontend hightlight translations

Tags: magento, frontend

I am trying to make Magento highlight translations on the front end of the website and show what file the translation is in.

I'm not really sure where best to start with this and cant find anything similar.

Edit: I managed to do this by extending the Translate model, was actually very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck! Magento has this built in.  Go to admin, and go to;

```
System > Configuration
```

From the top menu, then;

```
Developer
```

From the left menu (its at the bottom).

Open the 'translate inline' tab, and enable for front end.  Flush your cache and go back to the frontend. It will now show you the paths for labels which live in the /app/locale/[COUNTRY CODE] folders.

NOTE: Don't do this on a production site, as others will see the labels too.

Comment: Thanks for your response Pixie, I know about this feature and I should have pointed out that we cant use this. We want to enable it via URL etc "www.store.com/?showhighlights"

It also needs to show the name of the .CSV that the translation came from.

Comment: yeah that a very different question.